# "Link" items in a WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, adorner

I have a WPF `TreeView` that represents an object graph in which some objects implicitely references each others.

For those, I'd like to be able to draw an arrow linking them when I select one of them:

[image]

I looked into the [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) but I am not sure it's the correct way to go since I cannot find a way to get the graphical position of two items in the TreeView...

Any idea what I could do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you could get the relative item position with this:

```
var myItem = (UIElement)myTreeView.SelectedItem;
var pos1 = myItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(), myTreeView);
var pos2 = myAnyOtherItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(), myTreeView);
```

if you don't have access to the UIElement look for 
*["get container from data object (WPF TreeView)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433363/wpf-itemscontrol-get-container-from-data-object-treeview-multiselect)*
 but this is a other question and I'm sure there is already a solution ^^

second, using an adorner is good idea 
but I'm sure there are enough samples ^^